Riverpod: call async riverpod inside other provider
I am using Riverpod in my project, in one of my providers I want to call another async provider, SO this is my code:
@riverpod
class SelectedUser extends _$SelectedUser {
  
  @override
  List<UserModel> build() {
    return [];
  }

  void setSelectedUser(....) async {

 ref.watch(usersProvider).whenData((users) {
      //noting return back
     
      state = selectedUser;
    });

but When data never is called, I am sure the data in userProvider is returned but here, when data is never called. What is the issue? Is the correct way to call another provider inside another one?
When I am using final users = await ref.watch(usersProvider.future); I receive the result but whenData No.

.whenData means "is CURRENTLY data".  Not "wait until there is data".

OK, and how can I use it inside my provider?

ref.watch(statusesProvider).when(
    data: (users) {
      state = AsyncValue(users);
    },
    loading: () {},
    error: (_, __) {
      state = AsyncValue([]);
    });


In the other provider? really? If we want to use this structure, it is better to use provider.future

ohh got it, my bad. have you got an answer to your question?

I am using this structure await ref.watch(usersProvider.future)
